# Porting a C++ map with std::accumulate to PHP

Tags: php, c++, dictionary, porting

I'm not terribly well versed with array manipulation in PHP, so I have a simple porting question. In C++ I have a map `std::map<int, int>`, for which the implicit ordering on the key is a crucial part of the structure. What I want to do is to sum up all the values for an initial range of keys, which I do like this:

```
// accumulate helper, since "value_type" is "pair<int, int>"
int pair_adder(int n, const std::map<int, int>::value_type & p) { return n + p.second; }

// To add up values for keys up to N:
int total_value_up_to_time_N(int N)
{
  return std::accumulate(mymap.begin(), mymap.upper_bound(N), 0, pair_adder);
}
```

What would be an idiomatic way to write this data structure and accumulator in PHP?

To explain the context: The data structure is a simple time series, and I want to know how much I have accumulated at time `N`. The C++ `map` is always sorted by key, so I can add elements `mymap[time] = value;` in any order, and the map always contains the elements in time order.

To explain the accumulation: The `accumulate` function sums up all the map's values whose keys are no greater than `N`. For example, take this map:

```
 mymap = { { 1, 20}, {2, 30}, {3, -10}, {4, 15} };
```

Then for `N = 2` I accumulate 50, for `N = 3` I accumulate 40, and for `N = 12` I accumulate 55.

---

*Update:* I just realized that actually there's no reason why each timestamp should occur only once, so the data structure should really be a `std::multimap<int, int>`. The same accumulation function works verbatim, but if the PHP solution requires the time to be an array key, than that would no longer work. But this is not strictly important; I believe a solution in which each time is required to be unique will suffice.

Comment: Don't know much about PHP, but loved the `not terribly well versed` statement :-)

Comment: @Als: Thanks - I can certainly get by in PHP, but I really don't have the mental dexterity to think in terms of massively nested arrays, which seem to be a fundamental idiom in PHP. I just really miss my C++ containers :-) So I'm hoping that this sort of thing is easy fare for an experienced PHPer!

Comment: Sure thing, From your answers here, We know you are incredibly well versed in C++ :) just loved terribly and well versed going together in a statement, oh & sorry I didn't mean to spam. So, I will shut up now.

Comment: I'm not terribly well versed in C++, so I'm not completely sure what's going on here. Could you explain this in simple terms with an example PHP array and what you want to get out of it...? :o) Is this a simple one-dimensional map reduce as @Konrad suggests, or is there more going on?

Comment: @deceze: Thank you, very good point! I added some explanation. Please let me know if I should explain further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the PHP array map/reduce functions only map over values, not keys. If your map is using PHP `key => value` arrays, you'll need some tricks to filter out the values whose keys have a certain value. The easiest is a straight forward loop:

```
$map = array(1 => 20, 2 => 30, 3 => -10, ...);
$n = 3;

$result = 0;
foreach ($map as $key => $value) {
    if ($key <= $n) {
        $result += $value;
    }
}
```

From here you can of course get creative though:

```
$result = array_sum(array_intersect_key(
    $map,
    array_flip(array_filter(array_keys($map), function ($key) use ($n) {
        return $key <= $n;
    }))
));
```

Or:

```
$result = array_sum(array_map(function ($key, $value) use ($n) {
    return $key <= $n ? $value : 0;
}, array_keys($map), $map));
```

If you're using a more C++ like map, which in PHP would be an array of arrays, that simplifies the problem:

```
$map = array(array('key' => 1, 'value' => 20), array(...), ...);

$result = array_reduce($map, function ($v, $m) use ($n) {
    return $v + ($m['key'] <= $n ? $m['value'] : 0);
});
```

Comment: Hehe, nice one-liner :-) Though the manual loop is probably a bit more readable (and efficient?). Thansk!

Comment: Especially with your update concerning uniqueness of keys, see my update for a different array structure.

Comment: Nice, I like what I'm seeing!

Comment: The final `array_reduce` works very well, thank you -- unfortunately, it is about half as fast as the manual loop... but it's the answer in any case!

Comment: @Kerrek If you're using an implicitly ordered data structure like a [heap](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splheap.php), this could be made a lot more efficient by a loop that stops when encountering `$key > $n`. Hope this all gives you some inspiration of were to go with this... :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not super familiar with C++, but I'll try to give you a quick overview of arrays in PHP, then answer your question about summing.

Every array in PHP can be thought of as an ordered map. Unlike C++, there are no restrictions on type, an array is simply a map from key to value.

To create an array, you can use the following:

```
$arr = array();
```

To add items to the array, there are two ways to do it. First, you can use the `[]` operator to add a new element on to the end of the array. The key for this element will be (highest int key + 1), with the first key starting at zero. For example:

```
$arr[] = 1;
$arr[] = 2;
$arr[] = 4;
```

At this point, `$arr` is now a map with the following keys / values:

```
0 => 1
1 => 2
2 => 4
```

We can also add specific keys and values:

```
$arr[42] = 'cool';
$arr['foo'] = 'bar';
```

At this point the map will look as follows:

```
0 => 1
1 => 2
2 => 4
42 => 'cool'
'foo' => 'bar'
```

There's [quite a few functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) built in to PHP for working with arrays. For example, there are functions for sorting arrays (both by key and value, and in user defined ways), combining arrays, searching arrays, applying functions to all elements, reducing arrays, etc. Furthermore, the PHP construct `foreach` can be used to iterate over an array. Use it as follows:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Value of key ' . $key . ' is ' . $value;
}
```

Now, to address your question:

> What I want to do is to sum up all the values for an initial range of keys

Take note that if you add values in order, they will be in order in the array. If this is not the case, sort the array beforehand, then do the following:

```
$sum = array_sum(array_slice($arr, 0, $n));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you - but please observe that I need to restrict the sum over some arbitrary initial range of key values, i.e. I only want to sum values whose key does not exceed a given cut-off `N`. Maybe a sum over some subarray, or something like that. That's the extra magic contained in the `upper_bound()` function in C++.

Comment: `array_slice` seems to go by *position*, but I need to go by *value*.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there’s [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and a map is basically just an array. Hence:

```
$result = array_reduce($your_array, function($a, $b) { return $a + $b; });
```

should do the trick. Or just use [`array_sum`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) (thanks, deceze).

Comment: This particular piece of code can be summarized as `array_sum`. Not sure if this is what the OP needs though.

Comment: @deceze Oh. Nice. Been a long time that I’ve used PHP.

Comment: Mind you, I need to restrict the sum to those values whose key is no greater than `N`.

Comment: How to analyze key of map/array ?